# Pass a variable from component to index in realtime reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

So that i can pass function from index and get them called in dashboard.js using props, but now i would like to do the reverse, i would like the `<h1>{projectName}</h1>` in index.js updated when textfield has some input, but i have no idea how to do that

index.js

```
import .....

export default Home() {

const dosth = () => {//some actions};
const session = () => {//sth in api};

 return(
<div>
<div id="toolbar">
<h1>{projectName}</h1>
</ div>
<Dashboard session={session} dosth={dosth} />
</div>
)
}
```

dashboard.js

```
import .....

export default Dashboard({session, dosth}) {

useEffect(() => {dosth}, [session])

return(

const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState(null)

<Textfield value={projectName} onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)} />

)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you need to lift your state up the component tree..

In index.js,
you can use `usestate` for projectName and pass the `projectName` and `setProjectName` as props to dashboard component.

`index.js`

```
import .....

export default Home() {

const dosth = () => {//some actions};
const session = () => {//sth in api};
const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState(null)

 return(
         <div>
             <div id="toolbar">
               <h1>{projectName}</h1>
             </ div>
             <Dashboard session={session} dosth={dosth} projectName={projectName} setProjectName={setProjectName} />
          </div>
   )
}
```

`dashboard.js`

```
import .....

export default Dashboard({session, dosth, projectName, setProjectName}) {

useEffect(() => {dosth}, [session])

return(


           <Textfield value={projectName} onChange={(e) => setProjectName(e.target.value)} />

)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is recursively passing the setState function in index as a prop to the child component.

The other (better) way of solving your problem is by using a central state management system such as [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). Keep in mind that redux requires a lot of boilerplate, so you should probably go with react context.